# How do I mark a question as resolved without accepting one of the answers?

Tags: discussion, support

I asked a question that I later learned was impossible to accomplish. How do I mark it as resolved without hurting my accept rate or picking one of the answers, none of which answer the question?

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8856050/chrome-os-virtualbox-guest-additions/) is the question in question :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should post the answer to your question, and use the Accept answer feature. This is helpful, because future visitors/readers can quickly see how this particular answer is solved.

Of course, if someone else posts a better (more useful) answer, you should accept that answer instead.

In your case, you should post *why* "it is impossible to accomplish", with argumented reasons. Simply "No, it is not possible" is not a very helpful answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can answer your own question and indicate that it was impossible to accomplish, preferably including information on why it's impossible and what led you to this conclusion.  Then you can accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

Answer the question yourself with what you found to be the (non)resolution, then mark your answer as accepted.